# как исправить ошибку с gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp, sass

Установил node v6.9.5, npm 3.10.10(для компиляции sass) создал [проект](https://github.com/vov4ok/my_gulp), добавил пакеты залил на github. Тепер когда я его скачал на другой комп gulp не хочет работать сначала не видел переменной gulp я установил его глобально теперь 
вываливает такую ошибку

Error: Missing binding e:\work\my_gulp\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-4
8\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit
with Node.js 6.x

Comment: Возможно вам это поможет. https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После команди `npm rebuild node-sass` все зароботало.

Спасибо!